# Remove item from firebase recyclerview

Tags: java, firebase, android-recyclerview

public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {

```
View chatview;
String CurrentUserID;
FirebaseAuth auth;
String time , date ,CurrentDate;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
DatabaseReference ContactRef,UserRef;
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;

List<Contacts> contacts;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    chatview =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
    auth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    CurrentUserID=auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    ContactRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Contacts").child(CurrentUserID);
    UserRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    recyclerView=chatview.findViewById(R.id.chat_recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    floatingActionButton=chatview.findViewById(R.id.chat_float_btn);
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SendtoFindFriendsActivity();
        }
    });

    return chatview;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Contacts> options=new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contacts>()
            .setQuery(ContactRef,Contacts.class)
            .build();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts,ChatViewHolder> adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, ChatViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChatViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position, @NonNull Contacts model) {
            String userid=getRef(position).getKey();
            final String[] image = {""};
            final String[] name = {""};


            UserRef.child(userid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasChild("image"))
                    {
                        image[0] =snapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                        GetImage(image[0], holder.profileImage );

                    }
                    name[0] =snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    holder.lastSeen.setText("Date"+"Time");
                    holder.userName.setText(name[0]);
                    holder.userStatus.setText(snapshot.child("status").getValue().toString());
                    holder.lastSeen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (snapshot.child("userState").hasChild("state"))
                    {
                        String state=snapshot.child("userState").child("state").getValue().toString();
                        date=snapshot.child("userState").child("date").getValue().toString();
                        time=snapshot.child("userState").child("time").getValue().toString();
                        if (state.equals("online"))
                        {
                            holder.lastSeen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            holder.online.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }
                        else if (state.equals("offline"))
                        {
                            holder.lastSeen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.online.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
                            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy");
                            CurrentDate=dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                            if (CurrentDate.equals(date))
                            {
                                holder.lastSeen.setText(time.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT));

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                holder.lastSeen.setText(date);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent chat=new Intent(getActivity(), ChatActivity.class);
                            chat.putExtra("uid",userid);
                            chat.putExtra("name",name[0]);
                            chat.putExtra("image",image[0]);
                            startActivity(chat);
                        }
                    });

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }




    

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ChatViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_display_layout,parent,false);
            ChatViewHolder viewHolder=new ChatViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }

    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
}



public static class ChatViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView userName,userStatus,lastSeen;
    CircleImageView profileImage;
    ImageView online;
    public ChatViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        userName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);
        userStatus=itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_status);
        profileImage=itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_profile_image);
        userStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lastSeen=itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_lastseen);
        lastSeen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        online=itemView.findViewById(R.id.online_icon);
    }
}
private void SendtoFindFriendsActivity() {
    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), FindFriends.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
private void GetImage(String currentUser, CircleImageView imageView) {
    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().
            child("Profile Images/" + currentUser + ".jpg");
    storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            Glide.with(getContext()).load(uri).into(imageView);
        }
    });
}
```

}

can anyone tell me how Can I remove an item from firebase recyclerview .I am new in java app development that's why I am facing problem.

can anyone tell me how Can I remove an item from firebase recyclerview .I am new in java app development that's why I am facing problem.can anyone tell me how Can I remove an item from firebase recyclerview .I am new in java app development that's why I am facing problem.

Comment: If you understand Kotlin and if you consider trying using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), I think that this article, [How to delete a record from Firestore on a RecylerView left/right swipe?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or [How to delete multiple records from Firestore using RecyclerView multi-selection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) will help.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the adapter (FirebaseRecyclerAdapter) correctly, it will always display the designated documents in the recyclerView, so in order to remove an item from that list, you'll need to delete it from the database (in your case 'Realtime Database'). Otherwise, anytime you'll remove it from the list localy, the adapter will quicly put it back in.

So in order to remove an item from this list my approach will be:
Assuming we need to delete a single item at a time (and not a batch of items)

1. figure out how to impliment the desired UI\UX element that will start the delete proccess.
2. echo the corresponding UID of the item to the viewmodel
3. delete the item from the database via the viewmodel
4. echo back to the front the operation result in-order to provide some feedback to the user (a popup displaying: "item removed!", "connection error" and such)

If I'm not mistaken, after the item is removed from the database, the adapter should automatically remove it from the list displayed to the user.

If it dosen't work, or this solution is sub-optimal for your specific endeavour i think you'll have no choice but to make your own adapter.